# Remove the same substring from each value in a column in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to do some data cleaning to a file. The particular field I'm trying to clean describe what file it originally came from. Thus, there is always ".csv" at the end of the value in the field. I would like to remove this part of the value but keep the rest.

Here is an example of the field:

```
File Name
bagel.csv
donut.csv
hamburger.csv
carrots.csv
```

I would like the field to look something like this:

```
File Name
bagel
donut
hamburger
carrot
```

Is there a way to do this in R? Any assistance would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's always better to provide a [minimale reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610):

```
field <- c("aa.csv", "bb.csv", "cc.csv")

gsub("\\.csv$", "", field)
```

Returns:

```
[1] "aa" "bb" "cc"
```

Explanation:

We can use `regex` to substitute the sequence:

"." (`\\.`) followed by "csv" (`csv`) followed by end-of-line (`$`)

with an empty string (`""`)

By following the suggestion from @G5W we make sure that, since we only want to remove the extensions, we don't accidentally replace the the string if it appears in the middle of a line (As an example: In "function.csv.txt" we wouldn't want to replace the ".csv" part)

Comment: `sub("\\.csv$", "", field)` might be safer

Comment: @G5W You are right and I updated my suggestion! Thanks for your comment.

Comment: This worked great thank you. I'll definitely add a minimal reproducible example next time.

Comment: Excellent attitude! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(FileName = c('bagel.csv','donut.csv','hamburger.csv','carrots.csv'))

df <- df %>% mutate(FileName = gsub("\\..*","",FileName))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `file_path_sans_ext` from `tools`

```
tools::file_path_sans_ext(field)
#[1] "aa" "bb" "cc"
```

#### data

```
field <- c("aa.csv", "bb.csv", "cc.csv")
```